# Getting Python variable definition called 'not defined'

Tags: python, constructor, self, python-object

I am not exactly sure what this error means.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File     "/Users/johndoe/Documents/CHOP_CPR_Project/CHOP_Apr07/CPRPageClass.py", line 21, in __init__
# Determine Left Side Vertical Axis
NameError: name 'size' is not defined
```

Relevant code for Class that I am attempting to construct:

```
def __init__(self, image):
    # Gather initial values
    self.image = image
    self.size = image.size
    self.pixel_array = np.asarray(self.image)
    # Determine Right Side Vertical Axis
    rsv_list = np.zeros(0)
    for i in range(int(.2 * image.size[1]), int(.7 * image.size[1]), 5):
        counter = 0
        for value in self.pixel_array[i][::-1]:
            if value != 255:
                np.append(rsv_list, counter)
                break
            else:
                counter += 1
    self.rsva = image.size[0] - int(np.mean(rsv_list))
    # Determine Left Side Vertical Axis
    lsv_list = np.zeros(0)
    for i in range(int(.2 * image.size[1]), int(.7 * image.size[1]), 5):
        counter = 0
        for value in self.pixel_array[i]:
            if value != 255:
                np.append(lsv_list, counter)
                break
            else:
                counter += 1
    self.lsva = int(np.mean(lsv_list))
```

It's been a while since I coded in python so I am pretty rusty. I was wondering if anybody could identify a solution to my error.

The command I tried to run in terminal that produced the error:

```
>> image = Image.open('chop_april07_Page_01.jpg')
>> test = CPRPageClass.CPRPage(image)
```

Comment: Show us the entire class definition, not just `__init__()`.  Or at least indicate where line 21 is.

Comment: It seems very odd that it's displaying the comment line `# Determine Left Side Vertical Axis` in the error traceback, as if it thinks _that_ is line 21.  Maybe it's getting confused by an old version of a `.pyc` file that never got removed?